# Colouring of lines in Highchart takes ages

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors, linechart

I have a [Highcharts line chart](https://geodata.unepgrid.ch/extras/graph_global_temperature_monthly.php) with ~150 lines. I am colouring each one over a gradient from blue to green to yellow to red, by circling through each line and calling a small javascript function to calculate the value for it.

[image: Line chart with the colors]

However, it took always quite some time to calculate these - and since a short time it really takes ages. No idea why it has slowed down so rapidly, as I haven't touched the code, I would have said.

The code for cycling through the lines:

```
    function(chart)
    { 
        // number of line in graph; for the last year to highlight, this is important
        var chart = this;
        var n = chart.series.length; 


        // color the lines
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var value=i/n;
            chart.series[i].update({color: getColor(value)});
        }


        chart.series[(n-1)].update({lineWidth: 4});
        chart.series[(n-1)].update({marker: {enabled: true}});
        chart.series[(n-1)].update({marker: {fillColor: '#000000'}})            
    });
```

And for retrieving the right color:

```
    function getColor(value){
        //value from 0 to 1
        var hue=((1-value)*240).toString(10);
        return ["hsl(",hue,",100%,40%)"].join("");
    }
```

Any idea how this could be improved, as the chart loads now in ~1 minute or so... Really to slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe wait to redraw the chart until after you change all of the series? You might want to try [this](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series.html#update) `update` option:

```
...
        // color the lines
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            var value=i/n;
            chart.series[i].update({color: getColor(value)}, false);
        }
        chart.redraw();
...
```

Comment: Wow, what a difference in speed! Cool! Thanks so much!